# SQLAlchemy Foreign Key allow null

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a database that allows for pdf data to be uploaded in different contexts. So I have a table that takes in websites, and a table that takes pdf data that comes from that website. So naturally, I should have some FK that links the two, and I do.

However, the same table that takes pdf data, I want to be able to give it just an arbitrary pdf that isn't attached to some website, which would make this FK null. SQLAlchemy allows for nullable FKs, but when this is actually implemented, I get one of two failures. Here's the code:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    url = Column(String(STR_LEN), nullable=False)
    text = Column(sqlalchemyText, nullable=False)

    pdf = relationship("Child", back_populates='parent')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True, index=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    parent_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey("parent.id"), nullable=True)
    text = Column(sqlalchemyText(2**32-1), nullable=True)

    parent = relationship("Pages", back_populates='pdf')
```

Now, when I try to populate the tables with pdfs from websites, everything works fine. But when I try to populate the Child table with a pdf that isn't linked to the website, I get either one of the following errors:

1. When I attempt to give the `parent_id` the value `None` or `null()` or `0`, etc, it tells me I don't follow the UUID constraint. That's fair and all, but I made it nullable, so I'm not sure how to actually give it a null thing.
2. When I attempt to just give it a dummy uuid, so that its just an orphaned uuid, I get the error that the Foreign Key constraint fails.

Ultimately, my question is: How do I make it so the foreign key constraint doesn't care when I don't want it to, OR actually give it this null value without it complaining?

I am working with a MySQL db, so if there's a dialect specific solution, that's fine (but I'd prefer it to be agnostic).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to my own problem, though its not my favourite, it works well enough...

Using the zero UUID helps with this, since its the same every time. You can call it with the code:

```
import uuid
zero_id = uuid.UUID(int=0)
```

I wrote a script that populates the necessary tables with a row containing dummy information with the zero uuid where it needed to be. That way I could simply link all my uploaded documents to that ID in the table. The FK constraints all work out, and the variable type is fine. It's just now I have a bunch of extra code that I wish I didn't have to have.